# container двигается вместе с img

Tags: html, css

При движении img на margin 50 px всё в container также передвигается

[image: img]

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lang {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.btn {}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="" class="logo">
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul type="none">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home.</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About us.</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio.</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Blog.</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact us.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="lang">
        <a href="#">EN</a>
        <div class="btn">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте `padding` вместо `margin`, марджин делает внешний отступ, по этому отступает от начала и сдвигает всё что ниже (а контеинер у вас как раз ниже)